# Always on top with Checkbox on Java

Tags: java, checkbox, always-on-top

Hello all I am trying to make a new software that it gives me modulo of any number I gave. What I want is I put a JCheckBox on my gui and when it's checked the window should be

```
setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

and when deselected

```
setAlwaysOnTop(false);
```

Some of my code is

```
boolean top = false;

    Check = new JCheckBox("Always on top");
    Check.setLocation(140, 105);
    Check.setSize(150, 20);
    Check.setSelected(top);
    Check.addItemListener(new CheckBoxListener());

    add(Check);
    setAlwaysOnTop(top);

    private class CheckBoxListener implements ItemListener{
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
            if(e.getSource()==Check){ 
                if(Check.isSelected()){
                    top = true;
                }else{
                    top = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setAlwaysOnTop` does not observe further state changes to your `boolean top.` It takes the **value** of top when it is passed.

In your listener, write:

```
if(e.getSource() == Check) {
  setAlwaysOnTop(Check.isSelected());
}
```

Comment: That's a shorter way yhank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
    if(e.getSource()==Check){ 
        if(Check.isSelected()){
            top = true;
        }else{
            top = false;
        }
    }
}
```

to

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
    if(e.getSource()==Check){ 
        setAlwaysOnTop(Check.isSelected());
        }
    }
}
```

(Also, look into the various `LayoutManager`s in Java; don't make a GUI with fixed positioning.)

Comment: Thank you it really worked, but I tried it on morning it wasn't. Really thank you..